# Unable to Read SSBO Data OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

For my OpenGL program, I need to input data to an SSBO, edit it in a compute shader, and read back that data every render loop. I'm having trouble reading data back from the SSBO onto the CPU side.

My SSBO data is an array of structs. I pad everything so it is in groups of four and it renders fine on its own.

```cpp
struct OceanVertex {
    GLfloat x, y, z; // current position
    float padding1;
    GLfloat ox, oy, oz; // original position
    float padding2;
    GLfloat nx, ny, nz; // normal
    float padding3;
    GLfloat a, b, c; 
    float padding4;
    GLfloat _a, _b, _c;
    float padding5;

};
```

I initialize the data into a vector of OceanVertices and then set up my SSBO:

```cpp
// m_GridSSBO: ssbo ID
// m_Vertices: std::vector<OceanVertex> of my vertex data
glGenBuffers(1, &m_GridSSBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_GridSSBO);

glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(m_Vertices[0]) * m_Vertices.size(), &m_Vertices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
```

Each render loop I dispatch the compute shader and read the new data back into my array of vertices. I assign a work group for each vertex in my array.

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_GridSSBO);

glDispatchCompute(m_GridSideDimension + 1, m_GridSideDimension + 1, 1); // launces this many work groups
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(m_Vertices[0]) * m_Vertices.size(), &m_Vertices[0]);
```

Here's what the compute shader looks like:

```c
#version 430 core

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in; // invocations per work group

struct ocean_data 
{
    vec3 pos; // current position
    vec3 opos; // original position
    vec3 norm; // normal
    vec3 htilde; 
    vec3 htilde0; 

};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer OceanData
{
    ocean_data gridVertices[];
    
};

void main()
{

    // just editing the x and y position of the vertex as a test
    uint currentIndex = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * gl_GlobalInvocationID.y;
    gridVertices[currentIndex].pos[0] = 10.0f;
    gridVertices[currentIndex].pos[1] = 10.0f;

}
```

The vertex data is being rendered fine, but isn't changing from it's initial values, so I'm not sure if its a problem with how I'm editing the data in the compute shader or how I'm reading the data back or something else.